# Mapping in java

Tags: java, mapping

I have  a map code in java.This is my following code.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("type", "One");
map.put("name", "Two");
map.put("setup", "Three");


System.out.println("Map Values Before: ");
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
for (Iterator<String> i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  String key = (String) i.next();
  String value = (String) map.get(key);
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

Here i am able to get the output.My problem is i need match each key values to separate strings for further use in my code.How to i can get each key value in separate strings.Please help me.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "each key value in separate strings". It's also not clear why you've got casts in the loop given that you're using generics. Additionally, you appear to have the whole code twice... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a guess at your meaning, you want to populate variables corresponding to the keys

```
String type; // gets the value "One"
String name; // gets the value "Two"
String name; // gets the value "Three"
```

Now I assume that simple code such as

```
type = map.get("type");
```

is unacceptable, or you surely would not ask the question, so you want some programmatic way of iterating the set of properties?

In which case look at the Reflection APIs.

Please confirm that this is the problem you're trying to solve, and have a look at the APIs, if you then have specific questions follow up ...

Answer (score 1):

This ill allow you to iterate through your maps keyset. However, depending on what you need Guava has a [bi-directional](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) map implementation which could be useful in your case.

```
for(String key:map.keySet())
  System.out.println("key: "+key+" value: "+map.get(key));
```

Comment: Both answers are good but I definitely recommend the for-each construction shown here to loop over an iterator.